# What is this unexpected behavior in Python's zlib?

Tags: python, zlib

I have an example in `zlib` that gives an unexpected result.

If I start with compressing a simple string:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> import binascii
>>> compressed = binascii.hexlify(zlib.compress('first_message'))
>>> compressed
'789c4bcb2c2a2e89cf4d2d2e4e4c4f05002651056d'
```

Now if I do the reverse I get exactly what I expected:

```
>>> zlib.decompress(compressed.decode("hex"))
'first_message'
```

However if I try this I get an unexpected result:

```
>>> d = zlib.decompressobj()
>>> d.decompress(compressed.decode("hex"))
'first_message'
>>> d = zlib.decompressobj()
>>> d.decompress(compressed[:-2].decode("hex"))
'first_message'
```

What am I missing here? Why do these two return the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that is how much decompressed data is available given the input.  A `zlib.decompressobj()` allows you to feed the object chunks of the compressed data, and will return as much decompressed data as possible.  You can then feed it more to get more.

You will get all the decompressed data if you only cut off the last four or five bytes, since you are knocking off the final Adler-32 check (four bytes) and possibly only the end code of the last deflate block and some unused bits to bring it to a byte boundary (one more byte).  Those are not needed to decompress all of the data, but rather are needed only to mark the end of the data and to provide a check on the integrity of the data.

Comment: Is there a way to make the decompression objects strict, that is, so it will include the last bytes too?

Comment: If you don't give the object the last bytes, how can the object include them?

Comment: I discovered this behavior in a `socket` example. I sent multiple compressed messages, separated by a predetermined separator. However, I accidentally received `compressed[:-2]` and it uncompressed ok. This is annoying because the next time I received the bytes that were left out, plus the separator. Hence the multiple compressed messages were out of sync and they couldn't be uncompressed properly...

Comment: Then why didn't you ask that?  That is your actual question, not your original question above.

Comment: Use `unused_data` to detect the end of the compressed data.  Keep feeding the decompression object your stream until you see your terminator show up in `object.unused_data`.  Then start a new decompression object and feed it the compressed data after the terminator.

Comment: Yup that is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the help.